# Есть на странице div как изменить его видимость?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть на странице div как изменить его видимость? Нужно спрятать его.

Comment: Больше подробностей! Что именно нужно сделать?

Comment: @cas-live купите/скачайте себе наконец какую-нибудь хорошую книжку и прочтите ее. Такие глупости просто должно быть стыдно спрашивать

Comment: Может тогда предложите какую нибудь книгу

Comment: Нет, книга тут не поможет. вот ответ на ваш вопрос может быть
"Азбука" или "Война и мир". Всё потому, что вы не видите что ваши вопросы покрывают слишком широкую область знаний, на них нет правильных ответов. Вот это почитайте, http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html . могу ещё добавить, когда задаете вопрос, попробуйте прочитать его и абстрагировавшись от задачи, задать его самому себе, и понять - понятно ли вам лично о чем он.

Comment: >Может тогда предложите какую нибудь книгу

может, вам  ее еще и купить? уж будьте добры погуглить. Между прочим, литература по JS обсуждалась и на этом сайте. Какой вы к черту программист, если даже гуглом пользоваться не умеете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Правильные show/hide/toggle](http://javascript.ru/ui/show-hide-toggle)

Answer (score 1):

display:none;

Answer (score 1):

Например через jQuery задать свойсто css

```
$('#mydivid').css("visibility","hidden");//спрячет
$('#mydivid').css("visibility","visible");//покажет
```

Comment: а не проще $('#mydivid').show() и $('#mydivid').hide()?

Comment: show/hide не visibility меняет, а display. Если автору надо что элемент все же был на странице и можно было расчитать например его размеры, то visibility то что надо